# How to declare a call a 2d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, global

I am trying to read an image's pixels and fill them in a 2d array; however, I don't know how to declare a global array? any help please?

Answer (score 2):

```
int [][] arr = new int[height][width];
```

Comment: well, I have already filled my array locally in one action class. But I need to access to it from another action class. I want to know if there is anyway that I can access to an array that is filled in one action swing let's say -Open- from another action swing lets say- Resize.